# Speeding up code to download files from a SFTP

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, pysftp

I wanted to check if there was a faster way to download data from an SFTP which doesn't exist in a folder on a physical computer. The issue is that these files are 5 minute interval snapshots and the current SFTP folders have thousands of them (literally every 5 minutes since at least August, 2016).

I plan on asking the client if they can clean up the SFTP and have a process for removing the older data, but in the meantime I would like to improve my code for downloading as well.

Essentially, I check each folder on the SFTP and then check the corresponding folder on my computer. If the file doesn't exist then I download it (I am using Windows 10 right now). Even listing all of the files and checking if they exist takes a long time though (1400 seconds for just one of the folders which means I can't possible try to run this every 5 minutes).

```
with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password, port, cnopts) as sftp:
    logger.info('Server connected')
    for folder in folders:
        sftp.chdir(folder)
        logger.info('Downloading data from the {} folder'.format(folder))
        for file in sftp.listdir():
            if file not in os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder.lower())) and sftp.isfile(file):
                logger.info('Downloading: {}'.format(file))
                os.chdir(os.path.join(path, folder.lower()))
                sftp.get(file, preserve_mtime=True)
```

Here is the exact filename structure for one of the folders:

filename-2016-12-06-08-55-05-to-09-00-17.csv

This one folder (out of 7 folders) has 30,000 files (only 129MB of data)

Comment: is there a consistent folder structure/naming convention? Instead of looking you could assume it was there and attempt to download based upon storage format/naming convention.

Comment: The folder structure is static, but the naming is not quite. The name of the file is filename-2016-12-07-20-15-04-to-2016-12-07-20-20-09. It looks like the seconds are variable. Well, I'll look more closely, maybe I can use glob and wildcards to replace the seconds

Comment: Could you provide an example of the structure/naming convention in your question? It may help someone provide a better answer. Ahh yes, the time makes it difficult.

Comment: Get a list of the files and start 4 threads each downloading a file

Comment: Also, what about compressing them remotely, downloading, then de-deplicating locally?

Comment: Perhaps looking into a library would help. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sftpsync/1.0.8 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sftpclone/1.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that it's going to be difficult to make this script significantly faster as `paramiko` is not known for being blazingly fast. If possible at all, this seems more like a job for `rsync` or the likes. If there's no `rsync` on the remote host, you could still try to mount the remote file system over sftp and run rsync locally.

Having said that, one thing I noticed is that the expression `os.listdir(os.path.join(path, folder.lower()))` is evaluated for every remote file, even though it only changes for every iteration of the outer-most loop. So you could construct that list once for every `folder` and then re-use it. I doubt that it's going to make much of a difference, however.

Comment: Nice catch on the listdir. I was able to edit the code and it should be a bit more efficient at least. Ultimately, I will just have the client set up some cleanup process to delete older data after I archive it and load it to the database.